# javascript pass function to onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I have to write a function which will create a HTML code of `a` tag and this function will also pass a function handler to `onclick` event of created `a` tag.
Code:

```
function a(text,functionHandler){
    return '<a href="#" onclick="'+functionHandler+'">'+text+'</a>';
}

//usage
var a1 = a('link',function(){
   alert('test');
});
```

Passing the function to string doesn't work.
So my question is: `how to pass a function handle to onclick event and get a HTML code of created a tag?`

Comment: function is a reserved keyword, use something else like functionName.

Comment: Did you try my last update ? Also, you should change the title of your question to be more precise on the fact that you need to return an HTML code that will contain the event functions.

Answer (score 5):

Your current approach has a couple of problems -

1. `function` is a keyword. You cannot use it as a parameter.
2. The way you are using it, you need function name here. Passing a callback won't help.

Rather than returning your anchor as a string, return it as an element -

```
function createAnchor(text, clickHandler) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');    // creates an anchor element
    link.href = "#";                           // sets the href
    link.onclick = clickHandler;               // sets the click handler
    link.innerHTML = text;                     // assigns the inner html string

    return link;                               // now return it
}
```

and then -

```
var myAnchor = createAnchor('link', function () {
    alert('test');
});

// Add this element wherever you want
```

See the documentation on **[createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)** and **[element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element)**.

**EDIT**

If you want to add this anchor element to an existing DOM element as a child, use the **[appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)** -

```
var myAnchor = createAnchor('link', function () {
    alert('test');
});

document.getElementById('x').appendChild(myAnchor);
```

**[Live JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aswXT/2/)**.

**EDIT 2**

If you really want your anchor string, then create the anchor element using the above function, append it as a child to your desired element, and then use `innerHTML` on the parent. The approach is demonstrated here -

```
function createAnchorString(parentId, text, clickHandler) {
    var link,
        parent;

    link = createAnchor(text, clickHandler);    // call the previous function
    parent = document.getElementById(parentId);
    parent.appendChild(link);

    return parent.innerHTML;
}

var myAnchorString = createAnchorString('x', 'link', function () {
    alert('test');
});

alert(myAnchorString);
```

[**Live Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aswXT/7/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dejwid/aswXT/
and as you can see it doesnt work with unnamed function

Comment: Yes, your fiddle works but I need a html code of the created `a` tag

Comment: Your answer is the best one but I still can't mark it as accepted because this solution works on appendChild...

Comment: @BjörnRoberg long story, bro ;)

Comment: @David: Is that a bad thing?

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this :

```
function a(text, callback)
{
    var obj = document.createElement("a");

    obj.textContent = text;
    obj.onClick = callback;
    return obj.outerHTML;
}
```

The question is : How will it handle the anonymous function passed as callback argument ?

**EDIT**
This should work now :

```
function a(text, callback){
    return '<a href="#" onclick="if(!this.fireFunc)this.fireFunc='
            + callback.toString()
            + ';this.fireFunc();">'+text+'</a>';
}
```

Just using toString() on an anonymous function permits you to get its code.

This is a very hackish way, and doesn't work on named functions (It wouldn't be hard now to make it work).

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/gZ3YD/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
     function a(text,function){
        return '<a href="#" onclick="myfunction();">'+text+'</a>';
     }

     function myfunction() {
        alert('test');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way using jquery

```
function addActionButton(caption, tooltip, callback) {
  el = jQuery('<a/>', {
    class: 'btn btn-outline-secondary',
    title: tooltip
  });
  el.click(callback);
  el.html(caption);
  el.appendTo('#buttonbar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(para1){
    console.log(para1)
}
let bar = "hello world"
someElement.onclick = function (){foo(bar)}
```

Comment: Hi there! So... it's a bad practice to "just put the code" in an answer. Could you add a little more context? Usually a small explanation of what you did would be enough. Thanks!